# ER diagram relationship and Bridge Tables

Tags: orm, foreign-keys, relational-database, foreign-key-relationship, er-diagram

I  have to design a database for buses timetables.
Entities:

- Bus        (idBus*)
- Stop       (idStop*,stopDescription)
- Line       (idLine*,lineDescription)
- Position   (lat,lon)

Some constraints are the following:

- Multiple Buses may operate for one Line (therefore BUS:LINE = **N:1**)
- One Line has many Stops , and from one Stop are passing many Lines (therefore STOP:LINE = **N:N**)
- One  Bus passes from many Stops and vice versa (therefore BUS:STOP = **N:N**)
- A Stop has One Position (therefore STOP:POSITION = **N:N**)
- A Bus has multiple Positions (therefore BUS:POSITION = **1:N**)

### **E-R DIAGRAM**

[image]

An example of modelling would be a bridging table for the STOP-POSITION relationship that would look like this: 
STOP_POSITION(idStop*,lat,lon) whereas *idStop* is the Foreign Key.

**In general:**

If i have an `idBus` i would like to be able to get the associated `idLine`.
If i have an `idBus` and an `idStop` i would like to have info on the itinerary of the Bus (which is the next stop , time of arrival, direction)
If i have  an `idBus` and an `idLine` i would like to get the itinerary of the Bus(all the Stops from where the Bus will pass and their order)

### Questions

1. The problem arise when considering the BUS-STOP relationship, because when i consider to know the id of the Stop and the id of the Bus then i will know a number of attributes like Direction,*ID of NextStop*, *TimeOfArrival*..
   How should i model those attributes?
   For example, every Bus is passing from multiple Stops and the progression is denoted by an attribute (e.g *progressiveStop*). How should i model this attribute?
2. Does it really make sense modelling the association of LINE-STOP?
3. Does it really make sense storing dynamic data in the database? I am referring to the BUS-STOP relationship.

Comment: This isn't UML, is it?

Comment: So why did you tag it UML? Oh, you removed the tag. Never mind :-)

Comment: You have one important information missing - what is the required functionality? There is no exact anwer for your questions.    1. why do you have BUS - STOP relation? I think you don't need it.<br/>2. LINE -  STOP is right, it models stops on one line<br/>3. what do zou mean with dynamic data?

Comment: @PetrPribyl i updated the post. Also with Dynamic Data i mean the position of the Bus in a certain time. This can be dynamic since i can pull it from the system in Real Time

Comment: I'm still not sure, if do you need BUS - STOP relation. Sequence of stops is given by LINE - STOP relation, am I right? Ad Dynamic Data - I don't know :) It is given by your system requirements. for example: if you need to store history, store BUS - STOP relation. If not, don't do it :)

Comment: I agree that a Bus-Stop relation is purely optional